# Why, in React, is display of a todo list so brittle?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, reactjs

I've been spending the past hour or two debugging how to get a slightly shinier todo list to appear in a webpage based on ReactJS. There are half a dozen or so checkboxes, intended to list more statuses than a monolithic "complete / incomplete", and I intend to display the text inside the TEXTAREA as it was entered.

At present I have not gotten text entered into the text area to display alongside the checkboxes.

My immediate code, with things commented out, is:

```
    handleClick: function(event)
        {
        var that = this;
        var new_id = that.state.id + 1;
        var child_data = {
            'id': new_id,
            'completed': false,
            'delete': false,
            'hidden': false,
            'unsure': false,
            'you-decide': false,
            'in-progress': false,
            'active': false,
            'background': false,
            'problems': false,
            'description': document.getElementById('description').value
            };
        var fields = ['id', 'completed', 'delete', 'hidden', 'unsure',
          'you-decide', 'in-progress', 'active', 'background', 'problems',
          'children'];
        var previous_keys = Object.keys(that.state);
        var previous_state = that.state;
        for(var index = 0; index < previous_keys.length; ++index)
            {
            if (previous_state.hasOwnProperty(previous_keys[index]))
                {
                var current_key = previous_keys[index];
                var current_value = that.state[current_key];
                /*
                if (current_key === 'description')
                    {
                    that.setState({'description',
                      document.getElementById('description').value});
                    }
                that.setState({current_key: current_value});*/
                }
            }
        previous_state.id = new_id;
        new_child = new TodoItem({id: new_id});
        new_child.setState({descripton:
          document.getElementById('description').value);
        if (typeof previous_state.children !== undefined)
            {
            previous_state.children.push(new_child);
            }
        else
            {
            previous_state.children = [new_child];
            }
        that.setState({id: new_id});
        that.setState({children: previous_state.children});
        },
```

Elsewhere in the render() function for TodoItem, I have:

```
        return (
            <tr className="todoItem">
                <TodoField id={"completed-" + that.props.id}
                  field="completed" />
                <TodoField id={"delete-" + that.props.id} field="delete" />
                <TodoField id={"hidden-" + that.props.id} field="hidden" />
                <TodoField id={"unsure-" + that.props.id} field="unsure" />
                <TodoField id={"you-decide-" + that.props.id}
                  field="you-decide" />
                <TodoField id={"in-progress-" + that.props.id}
                  field="in-progress" />
                <TodoField id={"active-" + that.props.id} field="active" />
                <TodoField id={"background-" + that.props.id}
                  field="background" />
                <TodoField id={"problems-" + that.props.id}
                  field="problems" />
                <TodoDescription id={"description-" + that.props.id}
                  id={"description-" + that.props.id}
                  />
                {/*
                <TodoDescription className={descriptionClass}
                  content={that.state.description}
                  />
                */}
            </tr>
        );
```

Looking at with the object inspector suggests that a TodoDescription element may be present as a empty string. The TEXTAREA it's supposed to be copying from, is:

```
                        <textarea className="description"
                        placeholder=" Your next task..."
                        onChange={that.onChange} name="description"
                        id="description"></textarea>
```

I've made [semi-]working commit; the code appears brittle and hasn't displayed the data entry form at all with some of my attempts.

How am I approaching this wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- Children should be constructed in a render() method, not appended to a state
- Refrain from calling `setState` to construct your initial child's state, use props and `getInitialState` instead
- Don't use `document.getElementBy...` use refs instead
- Specify `key` instead of `id` , don't bother appending the parent's key